# discord.js ClientUser.setActivity doesn't work with an activity type

Tags: javascript, discord.js

If I set a custom activity like so it works fine

```js
client.once(Events.ClientReady, c => {;
    c.user.setActivity("feedback");
    console.log(`Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});
```

However, if I try adding an activity type (see below) no activity shows up whatsoever (with no errors in console).

```js
client.once(Events.ClientReady, c => {;
    c.user.setActivity("feedback", {type: "LISTENING"});
    console.log(`Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});
```

When hovering over `{type: "LISTENING"}` IntelliJ displays the error:

```
Argument type {type: string} is not assignable to parameter type ActivityOptions | undefined
  Type string is not assignable to type Exclude<ActivityType, ActivityType.Custom> | undefined
    Type string is not assignable to type never
```

A similar error is shown if I try using a number for a type.
`client.user` vs `c.user` also changes nothing.

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question (which is a statement) is incorrect. This does work with an activity type. However, you are not supplying an activity type.

An activity type is a number - not a string. You can see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.6.0/typedef/ActivityOptions) what numbers may be used. For example, `ActivityType.Listening` would be what you are looking for, which resolves to `2`.

> A similar error is shown if I try using a number for a type.

I cannot reproduce this, which is actually valid input in TypeScript (and what one should be using). This would indicate a possible corrupt installation of some sort.

Comment: Functions with `{type: ActivityType.Listening}`.
Every piece of documentation I found instructed me to the syntax I used above